# connect.cursor().fetchone() not picking up results from SELECT

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm currently trying to get a row from a `table` after updating it, but it doesn't seem to work. I use a `SELECT`, then from `psycopg2`  `connect.cursor().fetchone()`, but it errors instead. I have looked this up for hours, but it does not seem like I am making any problems, but surely I am somewhere.

My code:

```
    connect.cursor().execute(f"UPDATE logChannel SET log_channel = {arg.id} WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};")
    connect.commit()
    connect.cursor().execute(f"SELECT log_channel FROM logChannel WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};")
    print(connect.cursor().fetchone())
```

The Output:

```
    print(connect.cursor().fetchone())
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

By the way, the `arg.id` and `ctx.guild.id` is all part of `discord.py`, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with this, but if you suspect it might I can give you more of my code. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Check the documentation: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `connect.cursor()`, `psycopg2` gives you a new cursor object.

What this means is that your `update` and `select` should work fine, but you are throwing away the results of both of those calls to `execute()` since you then open a new cursor.

Your code should keep and use one cursor:

```
cur = connect.cursor()
cur.execute(f"UPDATE logChannel SET log_channel = {arg.id} WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};")
connect.commit()
cur.execute(f"SELECT log_channel FROM logChannel WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};")
print(cur.fetchone())
```